# How do I insert to two tables in the same query and also use the identity from one destination table?

Tags: sql-server

I have one source table containing 50 columns and two destination tables containing 25 columns each.

> Source table A
>   Destination Tables B and C

Table B has an identity as a primary key. I need to insert the first 25 columns in table B, get the value of the primary key and insert the remaining values in table C with this primary key value.

It would be easy if it was single inserts but its a bulk insert. For eg:

```
insert into b(c2,c3,c4)
select c2,c3,c4 from a
(Now i need to pick the id from b)
insert into c
select id,c5,c6,c7 from a
```

and the rows need to match.

I`m a novice at SQL. Sorry if there are bad examples.

Comment: What should happen when more than one value is inserted into `B` then you will have multiple `ID`. Which ID you will use to insert into table `C`

Comment: So it should work like this. 1st row gets inserted. The id is picked from there. The rest of the colums along with this id are inserted into the latter table. I can join the two tables on the ID and retrieve the complete row containing 50 columns

Comment: Your statement is completely unclear. Can add sample data and expected output

Comment: so are you inserting multiple rows or a single row? there is no where clause on the insert so it looks like you're attempting to insert everything from table a to table b and c?

Comment: I would use `OUTPUT` clause in the first `INSERT INTO B` to get generated `IDs`. Also, original table `A` should have some `IDs` for each row. Using `OUTPUT` clause you should be able to have an intermediate table, where each row has an `ID` from table `A` and a fresh `ID` from table `B`. I would save these results of the `OUTPUT` clause into a table variable. Then you can use these results to join back to original table `A` and insert data into table `C`. If you edit your question and add a simplified example of your tables schema, you'll get a lot of detailed answers.

Comment: `A` doesn't have a unique `ID` and there may be duplicate entries in `A` which need to be considered as separate entries while inserting into `B`

Comment: @Tanner Im attempting to insert everything. But half the columns should go to `B` and half should go to `C`. And they should be linked on the generated for `B`

Comment: @BryanD'silva, if table `A` doesn't have unique `ID`, then the first step would be to add this unique `ID`. Either add an `IDENTITY` column to `A`, or insert all rows and all columns from `A` into a temporary table or table variable that has the same columns as `A` plus one `IDENTITY` column. After that refer to my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MERGE` with `OUTPUT`:

```
CREATE TABLE A(x INT, y int, z int)
CREATE TABLE B(x INT, y int, z int)
CREATE TABLE C(x INT, y int, z int)
GO

INSERT INTO A VALUES(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)

MERGE INTO B dest
USING(SELECT * FROM A) src ON dest.x = src.x
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT VALUES (src.x, src.y, src.z)

OUTPUT Inserted.x, Inserted.y, Inserted.z INTO C;

SELECT * FROM A
SELECT * FROM B
SELECT * FROM C
```

Output:

```
A
x   y   z
1   1   1
2   2   2

B
x   y   z
1   1   1
2   2   2

C
x   y   z
1   1   1
2   2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

IDENT_CURRENT('Your B Table NAME') 
It will get the last primary key of B Table